# How to include a github framework in a XCode Plugin?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, git

I want to use ObjectiveGit [ObjectiveGit](https://github.com/rowanj/objective-git) in my XCode **Plugin** and followed the instructions of the ObjectiveGit Readme.

XCode crashes with the following error message:

```
Library not loaded: @rpath/ObjectiveGit.framework/ObjectiveGit

Reason: image not found
```

How can i achieve that ObjectiveGit framework is included inside my XCodePlugin.xcplugin, so that i am able to share the plugin and of course XCode will not crash anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **Build Settings** of the ObjectiveGit framework (which can be found inside your Apps Frameworks group), 
change the **Installation Directory** to:`@executable_path/../Frameworks`

*in case of **ObjectiveGit**, one also has to delete the **Dynamic Library Install Name***

[image: ObjectiveGit Build Settings]

A colleague pointed me to the right direction.

Comment: One potential point of confusion (at least, it was for me): the first sentence of the answer says "Build Settings of the framework", but the screenshot shows the yellow toolbox icon which is indicative of the ObjectiveGit *target*, not the ObjectiveGitFramework project.  Following the screenshot worked for me.

Comment: DOESN'T WORK AT ALL! `Unable to create directory: ... (Permission denied)`